# Connecting to a MySQL db with the anylogic objects

Tags: mysql, anylogic

I'm trying to connect to a local MySQL database, with the anylogic object "database".

I'm using the type: "Other Database", and the connection URL: "Server=localhost;Database=anylogicdata;"

but I constantly get a RuntimeException saying: "not suitable driver found"
The help file says that you have to install the driver, but i don't know which or if it is my connection URL that is the problem.

Does anyone have some pointers to help me along the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to download and add the mysql-connector-java-*.jar file to the anylogic-project.
Then you have to type com.mysql.jdbc.Driver into the JDBC driver dropdown box. finally the connection string should look something like

`jdbc:mysql:[host/db]?:[port]`

another thing I found that might be helpfull to others, is that you can get the java connection from the anylogic db object: `database.getConnection()` this is very usefull if you want to create your own query. eg create a bulk insert instead of the single insert that Anylogic provides.

Answer (score 1):

You need a JDBC driver to be able to connect to a MySQL server from Java (that AnyLogic is based on) and you can find one [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). After you have installed the driver you should find it in the list of available JDBC drivers in AnyLogic. The name should be **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** if you chose the suggested one.

Comment: The driver doesn't show up. I think the problem might be that I'm on a 64-bit system and Anylogic and the msi is only 32-bit. the platform independent files does have 64 bit, but no installer. So i don't know where to place the files in order to get it to show up in Anylogic

Comment: okay. i've explored your solution a bit more. And to make it work there are some additional steps, you need to do.

first you have to add the mysql-connector-java-*.jar file to the anylogic-project, and then you have to **type**  `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` into the JDBC driver dropdown box.
finally the connection should look something like `jdbc:mysql:[host/db]?:[port]`

if you could add the additional steps to your answer. I can mark it as solved.

Comment: I think it is fairer if you answer the question yourself and mark it solved and vote my answer up for being helpful ^^ If you dont want to I can adapt my answer of course ;)